# Redirect loop to old URL on aspx site

Tags: asp.net, web-config, plesk

I inherited a site that worked on the domain.  
Hosted on a plesk server from GoDaddy.

I placed a new site on oldguard.org which is hosted on ionos (formerly 1and1) and is working fine as is...you can see it at https://oldguard.org.

I wanted to take the old site that use to be on oldguard.org (current plesk site) which I can't not get to load at all, and place it on a new domain http://demotoga.com.

I have checked the servers with the domains and everything seems to be pointing in the right directions. However, when you go to demotoga.com, you get redirected to oldguard.org which is hosting the new site. For some reason, the old site (plesk location files on Godaddy servers) will not load on demotoga.com no matter what I do. It just keeps redirecting to Oldguard.org.

I believe the problem lies in the web config file for the hosting files that are for the old site which use to live on oldguard.org but cannot locate why the site continues to redirect. Shouldn't the site appear on demotoga.com if everything matches up?

I've looked around and around and cannot find where it points to the oldguard.org URL. What other Information is needed to solve this issue? Happy to provide any coding or give additional information just not sure what is needed to solve this issue.

Full web config code can be found here:
https://www.oldguard.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/oldguard-oldwebconfig.pdf

Comment: The web.config will have connection strings, those might need to be updated if they are using IP addresses. The site might also be gathering information from the database.

Comment: The following is code from the web config file?
Does it have to do with this?

<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Redirects from old website-->
        <rule name="Redirect Maps" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{StaticRedirects:{PATH_INFO}}" pattern="(.+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="True" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps>

Comment: The full web config file code can be found here: 

https://www.oldguard.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/oldguard-oldwebconfig.pdf

Comment: @JayBHall When you visit `http://demotoga.com` there is permanent redirect (301) to `https://www.oldguard.org`. Have you checked the Global.asax file?

Comment: I'm going to suggest you post your web.config from the demotoga.org site so we can analyze the problem. I went to demotoga and it redirected to oldguard.org. If the problem is not in the web.config, you might consider checking web host provider to ensure the DNS level is not doing a redirection.

Comment: https://www.oldguard.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/oldguard-oldwebconfig.pdf

Comment: @ Mohsin - I have checked my Global.asax file and there is only the following line of code there. 

<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Nop.Web.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Comment: @bbcompent1

The following is the web config file that is for demotoga.com. There this is directly from the source files that are in the database.

https://www.oldguard.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/oldguard-oldwebconfig.pdf